# Genetic Algorithm for Sessions Scheduling

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, genetic-algorithm, heuristics

I watched [this video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/Charles/Algorithms-and-Data-Structures-Mike-Swanson-Genetic-Session-Scheduler) from Mike Swanson, where he needs an algorithm to plan the sessions for big events like PDC or TechED. I'm thinking about what's the best way to represent the solution. His approach is quite simple, he has an array where he maps an index to a timeslot-room and the solution is a simple array containing a list of these indexes, where each timeslot-room element is removed from the array after being picked.

For example, given 3 timeslots and 3 rooms, this is the array mapping the timeslots+rooms:
0: timeslot 0, room 0
1: timeslot 0, room 1
2: timeslot 0, room 2
3: timeslot 1, room 0
4: timeslot 1, room 1
5: timeslot 1, room 2
6: timeslot 2, room 0
7: timeslot 2, room 1
8: timeslot 2, room 2

Let's say there are 9 sessions to be scheduled in. A sample solution is 5,5,2,1,2,3,1,1,0 which translates in:
session 0, timeslot 1, room 2
session 1, timeslot 2, room 0
session 2, timeslot 0, room 2
session 3, timeslot 0, room 1
session 4, timeslot 1, room 1
session 5, timeslot 2, room 2
session 6, timeslot 1, room 0
session 7, timeslot 2, room 1
session 8, timeslot 0, room 0

(if it's not clear, the video quickly explains it very cleary at 25:30)

Now, I have a bit of experience with genetic algorithms and correct me if I'm wrong but I always thought that the solutions produced by crossovering and mutating the individuals have to be similar to the solutions that generated it? i.e. if I do a crossover between two solutions, the generated solution has to be very similar to the ones that generated it (and similar thing for the mutation). Isn't this how evolution works? It looks like that the way that Mark Swanson represents the solution doesn't take it into consideration.

For example, in the case of crossover:
Parent 1: 5,5,2,1,2,3,1,1,0
Parent 2: 0,0,0,0,4,3,2,1,0
Child:    5,5,2,1,4,3,2,1,0 (crossover index is 4 in this case)

The child has 4 genes in common with parent 1 and 5 with parent 2. But if you write down the actual solution as I've done above (session x, timeslot x, room x), you will quickly realise that the child solution has pretty much nothing in common with parent 2. Isn't this a problem?

Another example, for the mutation this time:
Before mutation: 5,5,2,1,2,3,1,1,0
After mutation:  0,5,2,1,2,3,1,1,0

This small change caused 6 out of 9 changes on the actual final solution.

Are these things I raised actual issues? Or it doesn't matter because the genetic algorithm will work well anyway? And if these are issues, can you suggest any better solution?

Another question I have is: what if a session has to be scheduled several times? How would you represent the solution in that case?

Any help very appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, that crossover operator mangles the input of the 2nd parent -- but that simply might not be very important! Provided the mutation operator only perturbs the solution slightly, you don't even need crossover to hill-climb towards a good solution, but having the occasional "severe mutation" (which is what this crossover effectively is) can help avoid you getting stuck in local optima.

Comment: I agree with you @satoshi that this seems like a poor model for a genetic algorithm. Meaningful recombination of short "good ideas" is the essence of evolutionary computing; undirected mutations don't effectively process the solution space.

Answer (score 1):

> What if a session has to be scheduled several times?

Create a [Lecture](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools-planner/blob/master/drools-planner-examples/src/main/java/org/drools/planner/examples/curriculumcourse/domain/Lecture.java) instance for each time a session needs to be scheduled en schedule the lectures instead of the sessions.